# How to upgrade snap packages using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, snap, n3dr

The aim is to upgrade snap packages, e.g. [n3dr](https://snapcraft.io/n3dr) and [informado](https://snapcraft.io/informado), using Ansible. The following task has been created:

```
- name: Install various snap packages
  snap:
    name:
      - informado
      - n3dr
```

**Attempts to solve the issue**

The following websites were consulted:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/snap_module.html
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/62492
- https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/blob/main/plugins/modules/packaging/os/snap.py

There seems to be no option to upgrade snap package using ansible

[A GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/652) has been created.

**Workaround**

1. remove the to be updated packages

   ```
    user@host:~$ sudo snap remove informado n3dr
    2020-07-15T10:21:18+02:00 INFO Waiting for
    conflicting change in progress...
    informado removed
    n3dr removed
   ```
2. run ansible again
3. the newest version of the [n3dr](https://github.com/030/n3dr) and [informado](https://github.com/030/informado) have been installed

**Question**

How to upgrade snap packages without removing them first, using ansible?

Comment: You should contact the Ansible module maintainer, listed on its web page, and ask for this functionality to be added. Or better yet, send them a patch, if you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess this functionality hasn't been implemented in the module because:

> Updates are automatically installed within 6 hours of a revision being made to a tracked channel, keeping most systems up-to-date. This schedule can be tuned via configuration options.

[snapcraft.io Getting Started](https://snapcraft.io/docs/getting-started#2)

It should be possible to update a single package using the command module:

```
- name: Update snap package
  command: snap refresh package_name
```